# Is there no extra intermediate subfactor for the basic construction?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, subfactors

Let $(N \subset M)$ be a unital inclusion of ${\rm II}_1$ factors, the basic construction is $N \subset M \subset M_1 = \langle M , e^M_N \rangle$.

*Question:* For any intermediate subfactor $N \subset P \subset M_1$, is it true that   $N \subset P \subseteq M$ or $M \subset P \subset M_1$ (i.e. no extra intermediate)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer came by a discussion with Keshab Chandra Bakshi.
Consider the subfactor $(R \subset R \rtimes  \mathbb{Z}/2)$, then $R \subset R \rtimes  \mathbb{Z}/2 \subset M_2(R) = R \otimes M_2(\mathbb{C})$ is the basic construcition, but $(R \subset M_2(R))$ admits continuously many intermediate subfactors which are conjugate to $R \rtimes  \mathbb{Z}/2$ by unitaries in $\mathbb{C} \otimes M_2(\mathbb{C})$. So the answer is no.